# How to mock a dummy grpc service with methods in Go

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I need to write a unit test for a function, which in its source code calls a gRPC method of a different gRPC service. My test results in a panic error because that gRPC service is not running on my machine. I want to create a dummy service in my test and that service must serve the method calling inside the source code. How do I do that?

Edit: Details
Source function:

```
func (s *mainType) MainGenerateBearerToken(inputs...)(output) {
        response, err := s.Subtype.SubGenerateBearerToken(context, authnPass, ttl)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &models.OCITokenResponse{Token: response.Token, ExpiresIn: ttl}, nil
    }

func(cl *Subtype) SubGenerateBearerToken(context,authnPass, ttl) (*BearerTokenResponse, error) {
    
    resp,err := pb.NewGrpcClient(cl.Conn).GetBearerToken_grpc(ctx, &pb.GetBearerTokenRequest{AuthnToken, BearerTtlValue:ttlNum)
    
    return &BearerTokenResponse{Token}, err
}
```

I'm writing test for the MainGenerateBearerToken() function, which calls SubGenerateBearerToken(), inside which the grpc method is called.

Comment: could you give little bit more details? like little bit of code so that we can better help ?

Answer (score 1):

A gRPC service client is a regular Go interface.

You can use tools like [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock) or [moq](https://github.com/matryer/moq) to generate a mock for any Go interface.

```
$ go install github.com/golang/mock/mockgen@v1.6.0
$ mockgen -source=my_service.pb.go MyServiceClient
```

Or

```
$ go install github.com/matryer/moq@v0.2.5
$ moq -pkg mock -out mock/my_service.go . MyServiceClient
```

That will generate `mock.MyServiceClientMock` that implements `MyServiceClient`. Then you can use it in your unit tests instead of the real gRPC client.

**Complete example using moq**:

**`my_service.proto`**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package main;
option go_package = "main";

service MyService {
    rpc Hello(HelloMesage) returns (HelloMesage) {}
}

message HelloMesage {
  string msg = 1;
}
```

**`main.go`**:

```
package main

import context "context"

//go:generate protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. -I=. my_service.proto
//go:generate moq -out my_service_mock.go . MyServiceClient

func CallHello(myService MyServiceClient) (*HelloMesage, error) {
    return myService.Hello(context.TODO(), &HelloMesage{Msg: "hello"})
}

func main() {
    // (omitted) call grpc normally ...
}
```

**`main_test.go`**:

```
package main

import (
    context "context"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func TestCallHello(t *testing.T) {
    myServiceClient := &MyServiceClientMock{
        HelloFunc: func(ctx context.Context, in *HelloMesage, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*HelloMesage, error) {
            return &HelloMesage{Msg: in.Msg + " reply"}, nil
        },
    }
    res, err := CallHello(myServiceClient)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, "hello reply", res.Msg)

}
```

To run:

```
$ go mod init myservice
$ go mod tidy
$ go generate
$ go test
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's appropriate to get rid of the grpc client creation in the **SubGenerateBearerToken** method (e.g. keep it in the Subtype or pass as an arg) you could easily create a simple fake client:

```
type fakeClient struct {
    grpc.YourClient // a client interface from your *.pb.go file
}

func NewFakeClient(_ *grpc.ClientConn) *fakeClient {
    return &fakeClient{}
}

func (fc *fakeClient) GetBearerToken_grpc(ctx context.Context, in *pb.GetBearerTokenRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*pb.BearerTokenResponse, error) {
    return &pb.BearerTokenResponse{
        // your fake response...
    }, nil
}
```